# How to install apt-get package in Amazon Linux machine

Tags: unix, linux-kernel, rhel, apt-get

How to  install apt-get in amazon linux machine,using yum or wget ,i searched extensively but didnt find relvant ..getting below message

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-33-94 ~]$ sudo apt-get update -y && sudo apt-get install -y 
linux-image-extra-$(uname -r)
sudo: apt-get: command not found
```

Comment: This question well suited for https://superuser.com/

Comment: I see an amazon-rds tag in the OP. How is this relevant to RDS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well figured out these commands hence answering,these commands will install apt-get and run docker as ec2 user

```
sudo yum update -y
sudo amazon-linux-extras install docker
sudo service docker start
sudo usermod -a -G docker ec2-user
docker info
docker run -it --rm tarunkumard/gatling:FirstScript
```